# NestJs/Swagger: How to add `additionalProperties: false` on an existing DTO class

Tags: nestjs, openapi, nestjs-swagger, express-openapi-validator

Hello I am new to `Nestjs` and trying to implement `additionalProperties: false` on a DTO class that already has properties on it. I see that the `additionalProperties` key can be added inside `@ApiProperty({ schema:  ... { additionalProperties : false} })` but I want to add it like this:

```
class SomeResponseDto {

  @ApiResponseProperty()
  text: string;

  @ApiResponseProperty()
  id: string;

  // maybe a new Decorator like this?
  @ApiAdditionalProperties(false)

}
```

...so that only `text` and `id` is allowed in the `SomeResponseDto`. I want to avoid having to define every class as a schema object inside the controllers.

I should note that I'm using `express-openapi-validator` with `nestjs/swagger`, and do not want to use the `class-validator`/`class-transformer` plugins, so that I can validate responses as well as requests by using just `nestjs/swagger` decorators.

I have also tried this:

```
@ApiResponse({
    status: 200,
    description: 'success',
    schema: {
      oneOf: [
        {
          $ref: getSchemaPath(SomeResponseDto),
          // additionalProperties: false,  <-- this gets ignored
        },
      ],
      // additionalProperties: false, <-- this throws OpenApi invalid response errors
    },
```

Is there any easy way to add `additionalProperties: false` on an existing DTO class?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a workaround: Post this code inside the `bootstrap()` method of the application

```
  const schemas = document?.components?.schemas;
  Object.keys(schemas).forEach((item) => {
    if (schemas[item]['properties']?.allowAdditional) {
      schemas[item]['additionalProperties'] = true;
    } else {
      schemas[item]['additionalProperties'] = false;
    }
  });
```

This code above will set `additionalProperties` to `false` by default.

If for some reason you have a DTO class that you want to allow `additionalProperties: true`, then inside your DTO Class, add the following decorator and property:

```
export class SomeResponseDTO {
  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  allowAdditional?: boolean;

  @ApiResponseProperty()
  text: string;

  @ApiResponseProperty()
  id: string;
}
```

This is a simple solution for `true`/`false` case, but can be modified as needed to handle other use cases.

I hope this helps someone!